# Postgres is using full scan instead of index?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables, one table is 150M records, the other is 1 million. The subset of rows I am asking is only about 400 rows. Despite that I am getting "full scan" in explain analyze. The query is :

```
with txs as (
  select 
       tx_id 
  from pol_tok_id_ops 
  where condition_id='e3b423dfad8c22ff75c9899c4e8176f628cf4ad4caa00481764d320e7415f7a9'
) 
select 
       e20t.time_stamp,e20t.amount 
from erc20_transf e20t 
cross join txs 
where txs.tx_id=e20t.tx_id;
```

Explain reports;

```
 Merge Join  (cost=38689523.80..103962768.64 rows=4325899145 width=40)
   Merge Cond: (txs.tx_id = e20t.tx_id)
   CTE txs
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pol_tok_id_ops  (cost=316.12..15969.27 rows=5622 width=8)
           Recheck Cond: (condition_id = 'e3b423dfad8c22ff75c9899c4e8176f628cf4ad4caa00481764d320e7415f7a9'::text)
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pol_tokidops_cond_idx  (cost=0.00..314.72 rows=5622 width=0)
                 Index Cond: (condition_id = 'e3b423dfad8c22ff75c9899c4e8176f628cf4ad4caa00481764d320e7415f7a9'::text)
   ->  Sort  (cost=462.60..476.66 rows=5622 width=8)
         Sort Key: txs.tx_id
         ->  CTE Scan on txs  (cost=0.00..112.44 rows=5622 width=8)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=38673091.92..39442551.04 rows=153891823 width=48)
         ->  Sort  (cost=38673091.92..39057821.48 rows=153891823 width=48)
               Sort Key: e20t.tx_id
               ->  Seq Scan on erc20_transf e20t  (cost=0.00..3543917.23 rows=153891823 width=48)
```

Tables are defined as:

```
\d erc20_transf
;                                        Table "public.erc20_transf"
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 id           | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('erc20_transf_id_seq'::regclass)
 evtlog_id    | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 block_num    | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 time_stamp   | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 tx_id        | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 contract_aid | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 from_aid     | bigint                   |           |          | 0
 to_aid       | bigint                   |           |          | 0
 amount       | numeric                  |           |          | 0.0
Indexes:
    "erc20_transf_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "erc20_transf_evtlog_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (evtlog_id)
    "erc20_tr_ctrct_idx" btree (contract_aid)
    "erc20_transf_from_idx" btree (from_aid)
    "erc20_transf_to_idx" btree (to_aid)
    "erc20_tx_idx" btree (tx_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "erc20_transf_evtlog_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (evtlog_id) REFERENCES evt_log(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "erc20_bal" CONSTRAINT "erc20_bal_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES erc20_transf(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    erc20_transf_delete AFTER DELETE ON erc20_transf FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_erc20_transf_delete()
    erc20_transf_insert AFTER INSERT ON erc20_transf FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_erc20_transf_insert()


 \d pol_tok_id_ops
                                 Table "public.pol_tok_id_ops"
      Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   
------------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 id               | bigint  |           | not null | nextval('pol_tok_id_ops_id_seq'::regclass)
 evtlog_id        | bigint  |           |          | 
 tx_id            | bigint  |           |          | 
 parent_split_id  | bigint  |           |          | 
 parent_merge_id  | bigint  |           |          | 
 parent_redeem_id | bigint  |           |          | 
 contract_aid     | bigint  |           |          | 
 outcome_idx      | integer |           | not null | 
 condition_id     | text    |           | not null | 
 token_id_hex     | text    |           | not null | 
 token_from       | text    |           | not null | 
 token_to         | text    |           | not null | 
 token_amount     | numeric |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "pol_tok_id_ops_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "pol_tokidops_cond_idx" btree (condition_id)
    "pol_tokidops_tx_idx" btree (tx_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "pol_tok_id_ops_parent_merge_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_merge_id) REFERENCES pol_pos_merge(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "pol_tok_id_ops_parent_redeem_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_redeem_id) REFERENCES pol_pos_merge(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "pol_tok_id_ops_parent_split_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_split_id) REFERENCES pol_pos_split(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So, why it is doing full scan on 153 million records when CTE scan reports only 5622 rows??? Or, maybe there is a way to force scan on an index somehow?

I am using Postgres  10.12 (can't upgrade, its a production machine)

**EDIT**:

Some benchmarks:

```
psql=> explain analyze select * from erc20_transf WHERE tx_id  in (1111111,2222222,333333,555555,666666);
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on erc20_transf  (cost=71721.16..2161950.95 rows=3852686 width=96) (actual time=1.420..1.482 rows=3 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (tx_id = ANY ('{1111111,2222222,333333,555555,666666}'::bigint[]))
   Heap Blocks: exact=3
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on erc20_tx_idx  (cost=0.00..70757.99 rows=3852686 width=0) (actual time=1.386..1.386 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (tx_id = ANY ('{1111111,2222222,333333,555555,666666}'::bigint[]))
 Planning time: 1.490 ms
 Execution time: 1.557 ms
(7 rows)

psql=> explain analyze select tx_id from pol_tok_id_ops where condition_id='e3b423dfad8c22ff75c9899c4e8176f628cf4ad4caa00481764d320e7415f7a9';
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on pol_tok_id_ops  (cost=431.34..21552.04 rows=7586 width=8) (actual time=1.431..5.851 rows=340 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (condition_id = 'e3b423dfad8c22ff75c9899c4e8176f628cf4ad4caa00481764d320e7415f7a9'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=133
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pol_tokidops_cond_idx  (cost=0.00..429.45 rows=7586 width=0) (actual time=1.355..1.355 rows=340 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (condition_id = 'e3b423dfad8c22ff75c9899c4e8176f628cf4ad4caa00481764d320e7415f7a9'::text)
 Planning time: 1.585 ms
 Execution time: 5.926 ms
(7 rows)

psql=>
```

Comment: have you done a recent `vacuum analyze` on both tables?

Comment: @melcher no, but these tables are insert only, if there is a DELETE , it will be once per day event, if ever.

Comment: Also can you see if `erc20_tx_idx` is usable? (e.g. what's the `explain` of `select * from erc20_transf WHERE tx_id = ?`

Comment: Or see if you have any invalid indexes w/ `SELECT * FROM pg_class, pg_index WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false AND pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;`, https://medium.com/carwow-product-engineering/problems-with-concurrent-postgres-indexes-and-how-to-solve-them-c57f7656c852

Comment: then just `analyze`, updated statistics are still essential for the query planner

Comment: @melcher yep, indices are usable, I added performance in `EDIT` section

Comment: Can you run `ANALYZE erc20_transf` and `ANALYZE pol_tok_id_ops` and then re-run the query explain?

Comment: @melcher re-run analyze on a 150 million table which is mostly `INSERT`-only ? The nature of the data is that it is append-only, deletes are rare event, and updates do not exist.

Comment: Yes - `vacuum` may be unnecessary, but out of date table statistics (fixed by `analyze`) can cause postgres to use (wildly) incorrect query plans that cause significant performance issues. If the table hasn't been analyzed recently I would start there.

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112722/analyze-strategy-for-big-tables-in-postgresql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236712/discussion-between-melcher-and-nulik).

Comment: @melcher it worked! I ran `vacuum analyze` and after it finished, the query is fast now. no sequential scan is done. `Execution time: 5.129 ms` , thanks a lot!

Comment: so basically we can conclude from this that postgres planner is broken, I hope they fix the bugs soon

Comment: @melcher answer the question with `vacuum analyze` and and I will accept the answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `vacuum analyze [table-name]` (or just `analyze [table-name]`) to update the query planner statistics.

For large or frequently updated tables, PostgreSQL recommends tuning the auto-analyze (and generally auto-vacuum) settings to fit your needs. If postgres is using out of date table statistics (that don't reflect the current content/distribution of the table) it can come up with bad to terrible query plans.

Also, for unevenly distributed data on a large table (where the sampling techniques postgres uses won't always accurately reflect the underlying data, depending on the sample) you may need to tweak the target statistics.
See [Analyzing Extreme Distributions in Postgres](https://engineering.zalando.com/posts/2015/07/analyzing-extreme-distributions-in-postgresql.html) and [Analyze Strategy for big tables in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112722/analyze-strategy-for-big-tables-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps. It would seem to be the JOIN. You have

```
    ... 
    select 
           e20t.time_stamp,e20t.amount 
    from erc20_transf e20t 
    cross join txs 
    where txs.tx_id=e20t.tx_id;
```

JOINS typically are performed before WHERE and **cross join** will combine every row erc20_transf with eveny row txs, then apply the WHERE.
Try an INNER JOIN:

```
    ... 
    select 
           e20t.time_stamp,e20t.amount 
    from erc20_transf e20t 
    join txs on (txs.tx_id=e20t.tx_id);
```